# Using Expo React Native in Monorepo without Yarn

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, monorepo, turborepo

I have been trying to setup a monorepo using turborepo. I want to have a Nextjs application along with a React Native application (using Expo).

I have come as far as getting everything to work using yarn and it's no-hoist options as well as expo-yarn-workspaces. You can see my repo here: https://github.com/juliusmarminge/turbo-expo-next-starter. This is my first monorepo so not sure if it follows conventions by any means.

The issue I'm getting into is I don't want to be forced to use Yarn, especially since pnpm is getting more popular and I use it for most my other projects. Has anyone any experience in using Expo in a monorepo without using Yarn? Feels like all examples online is using it...

Thanks in advance,
Julius

Answer (score -2):

You can use it with pnpm AND get-workspaces (from yarn) to update your metro.config.js and to resolve node_modules.

Comment: Can you provide example use in metro.config.js

Comment: Can you provide any more info?